# how to extract value from line found

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm opening a file and finding the line I need, but then I have trouble creating a variable from the found string

```
70c 08:04:04.014    rexx    TRACE   2203 8=4.4|9=892|35=J|49=ICE_SM_S|56=SM|34=280|70=0241608914160889|71=0|626=2|793=16|72=|466=1164266784|857=0|73=1|11=|37=1156426784|526=1156426674|38=1|198=1310883PTM|54=1|6=117.2100000000|336=R|625=P|55=B|461=FXXXXX|200=20120901|207=IFEU|53=1|30=ICE|453=2|448=SLM|447=C|452=7|448=FFC|447=C|452=12|75=20120210|60=20120310-09:04:04|77=O|58=CYU795|232=14|233=GL_TRADEJOBOUT|234=N|233=GL_ORDERJOBOUT|234=N|233=GL_TAKEN|234=0|233=GL_TRADETYPE|234=E|
```

This is the string and I want to assign it to a variable of `tag198`, so it would be

```
tag198 = '1310883PTMS'
```

Anything after `|` is not needed.

```
tag198 = line.match(/198=(.*)/)[1]
puts tag198
```

but that keeps all after `198`; I need just the string prior to the `|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression's `*` is greedy, and will consume all characters it can without stopping the rest of the expression from matching. There is nothing in the expression that tells ruby when to stop collecting characters.

Look at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html). A partial fix for your problem would be to put a '|' after your capture:

`tag198=line.match(/198=(.*)\|/)[1] puts tag198`

The '|' is escaped as it has special meaning in regexes otherwise. This doesn't yet work though, because the `*` can still consume '|' characters, so long as it leaves one behind to match the '|' in our expression. To fix completely, prevent the `*` from capturing any pipes:

`tag198 = line.match(/198=([^|]*)\|/)[1] puts tag198`

See results of this change [here](http://repl.it/CKq).

Comment: I tried your regular expression `/198=(.*)\|/` and it didn't match  correctly (same problem as the OP) @ctcherry's solution does work.

Comment: 'line.match(/198=(.*)\|/)[1]` ---still leaves the trace

Comment: Thanks @TomasKlein; can you mark the answer as accepted (hit the tick beside the up/down arrows on the left)?

Answer (score 3):

Change your regular expression to:

```
/198=(.+?)\|/
```

That makes it non-greedy and stop at the vertical bar. You have to escape the vertical bar because it normally would mean "OR" in a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only letters and numbers you could use

```
    /198=([A-Za-z0-9]*)/
```

Also, in case you didn't know, you can test regular expressions on rubular.com, it also provides some information about special charters in regular expressions, it is a great site for all your regular expressions needs even if it isn't for ruby.